# 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Distinct'

Tags: c#

Getting error in this code:

```
 var distinctDateValues = dt.AsEnumerable()
       .Select(row => DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("DATE")))
       .Distinct()
       .OrderByDescending(x => x)
       .ToList();
```

> 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection' does not
>   contain a definition for 'Distinct' and no extension method 'Distinct'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am using this code in my CLR procedure. Please suggest how can I add the dll. While adding reference it does not show System.Linq in SQL reference tab.

Edit: I am using 3.5 framework and Visual Studio 2010 CLR project

Comment: Please show a short sample `DataTable` which demonstrates this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Include reference of `System.Core` in your project

and

Import `System.Linq` in your code.

**Additional Note:**

Going by the comments on my answer, most will think that in this case `Select` will also not work. But that is not the case.

`Select` comes from `System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions` where as `Distinct` comes from `System.Linq.Enumerable`.

[image]

Comment: @user1254053: Updated answer. Please check.

Comment: @TimSchmelter [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907949.aspx) and [`AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx), I guess.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: never noticed that `Linq-To-DataTable` uses a different `Select` +1

Comment: So to Import System.Linq, I have to first deploy the assembly in sql server and then add the reference in CLR project, correct?

Comment: Take reference in your project only. This dll is part of .net and is available wherever .Net is installed.

Comment: In CLR project I can only see the SQL Server tab when Add Reference is clicked

Comment: And I do not see System.Linq here

Comment: First add reference of System.Core in your project.